# Does Azure explain API version updates for resources?

Tags: azure

Resources in Azure have an API version, with most having several API versions, as seen in the [Azure docs here for SQL Server databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/2017-10-01-preview/servers/databases).

You can see even more API versions by using the `Get-AzureRmResourceProvider` PowerShell command, like so:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> ((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.SQL).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq servers/databases ).ApiVersions
2018-06-01-preview
2017-10-01-preview
2017-03-01-preview
2015-05-01-preview
2015-01-01
2014-04-01-preview
2014-04-01
2014-01-01
```

Does Azure explain updates to the API versions anywhere?

Comment: There are many update version of API azure released and some are still on continuous enhancement, can you please specify which one you would like o know? For example azure active directory releases endpoint V2.0 and still developing.